# Unexpected initial token 'EndObject' when populating object exception deserializing abstract class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I wrote a custom JSON converter class in json.net and cannot figure out why I am getting the following exception when I deserialize with it.

> Unexpected initial token 'EndObject' when populating object. Expected JSON object or array. Path '', line 1, position 177.

I have other converters in my project which are modeled very similar which work without issue so I am unsure why this is being such a problem.

Here is the object being serialized:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CreateCRMIntegrationPromptJsonConverter))]
public abstract class CreateCRMIntegrationDirectPromptBaseBindingModel
{
    public bool IncludeInOutput { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public IValidateCRMField Validator { get; set; }
    public string ValidatorType { get; set; }
    public CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType Type { get; set; }
}
public class CreateCRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneBindingModel : CreateCRMIntegrationDirectPromptBaseBindingModel
{
    public bool FormatPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And the converter

```
public class CreateCRMIntegrationPromptJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Models.CreateCRMIntegrationDirectPromptBaseBindingModel);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            JsonReader jsonReader = jo.CreateReader();
            Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>(jo.ToObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            var typeValue = values["type"].ToString();

            Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType integrationPromptType = Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType.Label;

            if (!Enum.TryParse(typeValue, out integrationPromptType))
            {
                integrationPromptType = Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType.Label;
            }

            switch (integrationPromptType)
            {
                .........
                case Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType.MobilePhone:
                    Models.CreateCRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneBindingModel cRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneReturnModel = new Models.CreateCRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneBindingModel();
                    serializer.Populate(reader, cRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneReturnModel);
                    return cRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneReturnModel;
                .........
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Models.CreateCRMIntegrationPromptLabelBindingModel cRMIntegrationPromptLabelReturnModelDefault = new Models.CreateCRMIntegrationPromptLabelBindingModel();
            cRMIntegrationPromptLabelReturnModelDefault.IncludeInOutput = false;
            cRMIntegrationPromptLabelReturnModelDefault.Label = string.Empty;
            cRMIntegrationPromptLabelReturnModelDefault.Type = Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType.Label;
            return cRMIntegrationPromptLabelReturnModelDefault;
        }
    }
}
```

When I test with this code I can catch the exception

```
var obj = new CreateCRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneBindingModel();
obj.IncludeInOutput = true;
obj.FormatPhoneNumber = true;
obj.Label = "Test";
obj.ValidatorType = "Answer1APILib.CRMIntegration.ValidateCRMField_NonRequired";
obj.Type = CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType.Label;
obj.Value = "";
var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateCRMIntegrationDirectPromptBaseBindingModel>(test);
```

Here is the JSON returned by the serialization

```
{  
   "FormatPhoneNumber":true,
   "IncludeInOutput":true,
   "Label":"Test",
   "Value":"",
   "Validator":null,
   "ValidatorType":"Answer1APILib.CRMIntegration.ValidateCRMField_NonRequired",
   "Type":0
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the `jsonReader` to `serializer.Populate()` rather than the incoming `reader`.  Or eliminate the variable `jsonReader` entirely and pass in `jo.CreateReader()`:

```
serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), cRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneReturnModel);
```

You need to do this because you previously loaded the object at the initial location of the incoming `JsonReader reader` into `JObject jo`:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
```

Thus the incoming `reader` has been advanced past the object and on to whatever comes next.  Using the `reader` a second time to populate you model will advance the reader further still, eventually causing the `Unexpected initial token 'EndObject'` you are seeing.

You might also want to check to see whether the incoming JSON token is `null` before loading it as an object:

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
    return null;
JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
```

Since a `null` value in JSON file is actually loaded as a *non-null `JValue`* with [`JValue.Type`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Type.htm) equal to [`JTokenType.Null`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm), attempting to load such a token as a `JObject` will fail.

(Finally, I'm not sure I would handle exceptions in `ReadJson()` itself.  Newtonsoft already has a [mechanism for handling exceptions](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) and if you catch and swallow all exceptions inside `ReadJson()` rather than using the mechanism there's a chance you could fall into an infinite loop when reading a malformed, truncated JSON file.  This is not the primary cause of the problem you are seeing though.)

Thus a fixed version of `ReadJson()` would look like:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        return null;                
    var jo = JObject.Load(reader);

    var typeValue = (string)jo.GetValue("Type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);            
    Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType integrationPromptType;
    if (!Enum.TryParse(typeValue, out integrationPromptType))
    {
        integrationPromptType = Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType.Label;
    }

    Models.CreateCRMIntegrationDirectPromptBaseBindingModel model;
    switch (integrationPromptType)
    {
        case Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType.MobilePhone:
            model = new Models.CreateCRMIntegrationPromptMobilePhoneBindingModel();
            break;

        case Models.CRMIntegrationDirectPromptType.Label:
            model = new Models.CreateCRMIntegrationPromptLabelBindingModel();
            break;

        // Add other cases as required.

        default:
            throw new JsonSerializationException(typeValue);
    }

    serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), model);
    return model;
}
```

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XOHR6r).